# What's wrong with my python "in" keyword?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am new to Python, I know the "in" word is used to see whether a string is the substring of another string or not. But when I use the "in" like this, something wired happened:

```
Input:

c=['1234444', '56788888', '99999900']
print "dddd" in c[0] 
print "ffffff" in c[1]
print np.arange(len(c)-1 ) 
if((("ddd" in c[i]) and ("fffff" in c[i+1]))for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 )):
    print c
    print "Something wrong"

Output:

False
False
[0 1]
['1234444', '56788888', '99999900']
Something wrong
```

Why the if clause is "True"? Shouldn't it be false? Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You produced a generator expression but you don't loop ever it. A generator object is 'not empty' so `True`. The expressions in the generator expression are otherwise never executed.

For example:

```
>>> gen = (False for _ in range(0))  # always false *and* empty
>>> bool(gen)
True
```

Perhaps you were looking for the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)? It'll iterate over its argument and return `True` if any of its values are true:

```
if any("ddd" in c[i] and "fffff" in c[i+1]) for i in np.arange(len(c)-1)):
    print "Never reached"
```

There is a corresponding [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
((("ddd" in c[i]) and ("fffff" in c[i+1]))for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 ))
```

is a generator.

If you do

```
if((("ddd" in c[i]) and ("fffff" in c[i+1]))for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 ))
```

you are not iterating through the generator, you are basically saying "is this generator something* ", which it is.

<sub>(* where "something" is not `None` or zero or an empty container or some otherwise falsey object)</sub>

If you want to check that everything in the generator is true, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

```
if all((("ddd" in c[i]) and ("fffff" in c[i+1]))for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 ))
```

If you want to check if anything in the generator is true, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).

```
if any((("ddd" in c[i]) and ("fffff" in c[i+1]))for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to your question.

You are feeding in `("ddd" in c[i])` which yields "False" and `("fffff" in c[i+1])` which also yields "False" to if statement.

So basically you are saying

```
if((False and False)for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 )):
```

Now, False and False  = False

```
>>> False and False
False
```

So your if statements reduces to

```
if( False for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 )):
```

Above list comprehension is equivalent to :

```
temp = []
for i in np.arange(len(c)-1 ):
temp.append(False)
```

The result of above is True. i.e. you are appending "False" for every iteration of for loop.
 Hence following statements within if gets executed.

```
print c
print "Something wrong"
```